# Getting a false text label instead of remote custom message

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter, jquery-validate

I'm Using Jquery.validate.js after validating that email exists in database it outputs false in the input box label instead of the custom remote message, server throws true or false back to the client-side validation .. if it returns true, means email is available and vice versa

what seems to be the problem or am I missing something?

I tried putting this in the email rule, and it outputs normally (true or false)

```
success: function(data){
       console.log(data);
}
```

here's the back-end

```
 public function isEmailAvailable()
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');



        $data['email']=htmlspecialchars($email);
        $result = $this->createuser_model->isEmailAvailable($data);

        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

here's the validation

```
    email:{
                required: true,
                email: true,
                minlength: 4,
                "remote":
                {
                    url: baseurl + "/admin/isEmailAvailable",
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data:
                    {
                            email: function()
                            {
                                return $('#createForm :input[name="email"]').val();

                            }
                    }
                }

        },
```

here's the message

```
 messages:
    {
        email:{
           required: "<span class='text-danger'>Please enter an email address.</span>",
           email: "<span class='text-danger'>Please enter a valid email address.</span>",
           remote:  jQuery.validator.format("{0} is already taken.")
        },
}
```

I'm was expecting a (emal@domain.com is already taken.) output...
instead I get a "false" text displayed in the label

Comment: You would not normally use a parameter `{0}` in the error message with `remote`.  See my comment on your answer.

Comment: the `{0}` is where the unavailable email be inserted, output will be like this: *_name@domain.com_ is already taken.*.. thats the given sample in jquery validation documentation...

Comment: Yes, I know that's how parameters work, but that's not how you typically do it with the `remote` method.  Since any JSON encoded string can be echo'd back from the server, it's far easier and much more reliable to just do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! Instead of putting json_encode() I just used echo

```
public function isEmailAvailable()
    {
        $email = $this->input->post('email');



        $data['email']=htmlspecialchars($email);
        $result = $this->createuser_model->isEmailAvailable($data);

        echo $result;
    }
```

Comment: Response must be JSON encoded string.  So what happens when the email already exists?  Normally for `remote`, the error message is dynamically constructed on the server and returned as a JSON encoded string:  `echo json_encode("John Doe email already exists")`

Comment: The server only throws the **true** or **false** not the entire "John Doe email already exists", according to [remote documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/)    The serverside response must be a JSON string that must be "true" for valid elements, and can be "false", undefined, or null for invalid elements

Comment: I helped write that part of the documentation and for some reason you're ignoring the rest of that paragraph:  *["If the **serverside** response is a string, eg.  'That name is already taken, try peter123 instead', this string will be displayed as a custom error message in place of the default."](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/)*  - I've used CodeIgniter with the `remote` method myself on many occasions, all using dynamic custom error messages, and never saw the error you describe.

Comment: Its an honor to talk to one of the devs who made that very handy plugin!
I never noticed that, deep dive on those later Thanks for informing

Comment: Thank you but I did not develop it ... I only help out with cleaning up the docs and [answering a ton of questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3794/jquery-validate).

Comment: yeah its kinda odd , Iv'ed used this before on my 2nd yr college, never Encountered this, but its fixed now .. I just removed the `json_encode()` and used `echo $variable` instead... works fine :)

Comment: That's because you can echo a boolean response and it still works.  If you encounter a situation where the server responds with anything but a true/false, you might have a problem.  If it were my project, I'd put back the JSON encoding, construct the message on the server, and remove the custom message from the jQuery object... it makes everything a bit more reliable and inline with typical usage and documentation.

Comment: Yes, I implemented the custom message from the server, It's so lit..  really made my development easy Thanks again!